# google drive desktop app cannot switch account

Tags: windows, google-drive

So here's whats happened; my friend helped me install google drive as a local drive on my computer , which looks like this;

[image]

and I have the need to switch to another account.
The problem is, according to articles on the web, I should be able to open the google drive app ,which looks like this:

[image]

but I am unable to open the this app page. If I go to windows here, and i click the google drive app (as shown below)
[image]

only my local disk
[image]

pops back out at me!

If I uninstall google drive and install it again, it says that i have a partially deleted google drive, and tells me to reboot my computer. When I do as it says, it installs google drive as a local drive into my computer, and i am still unable to switch accounts or open the app page.

Help!

p.s. I have looked at a lot of the articles describing changing accounts, but to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

Clicking on `Google Drive` from <kbd>Win</kbd> will run google drive, *Which it is, already*. 
Google drive, get minimised to system tray when run.

To change your account,

1. Go to tray, click [image]
2. Click the gear-like icon, go to preferences. *This is the window you were expecting...*
3. Click the profile icon, and `Add account`. Or if the account is already logged in, just click on it.